# (WPF) When binding to TreeView, is it possible to filter item by conditional property of the element of the collection that are the binding source?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

For example,

```
// Element Type
public class TreeNode
{
    public bool IsDisabled { get; set; }
    public List<TreeNode> Children { get; set; }
}

// Binding Source
public List<TreeNode> TreeNodes { get; set; }

// In xaml
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeNodes}"/>

// At the time of binding
TreeNodes = PreconfiguredCollection;

// A lot of code has been omitted for explanation.
```

Is it possible to check the `TreeNode.IsDisabled` property at the time of binding TreeNodes collection to the TreeView control, so that certain tree nodes are filtered out? Of course, children of the tree node are also filtered.

The main purpose is to prevent the creation of an inner wrapping object used for UI virtualization. TreeView control is UI virtualization enabled. Is there a method I can override?